# Koin scope with multiple declarations?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

As per this article https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/getting-started/android-scope/ we can create scopes for our objects. This is an example given there.

```
scope("session") { MyScopePresenter(get())}
```

My question is that are we allowed to put in multiple definitions per scope? I feel we are not. There is no examples anywhere showing such.

```
    scope("session") {  
       Something() 
     AnotherThing()}
```

This doesn't work . I can only inject AnotherThing() while as something is not injected.

Why does Koin just allow one definition per scope?

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding your declarations to the `module { ... }` using the `single`, `factory` or `scope` definitions, internally they create so-called `BeanDefinition` object. This bean definition object will provide instances of declared objects. Each `BeanDefinition` object will handle one declaration. That means that you should change

```
scope("session") {  
   Something() 
   AnotherThing()
}
```

into

```
scope("session") { Something() }
scope("session") { AnotherThing() }
```

in order to make it work.